# How I can do a reference code in my C# documentation?

Tags: c#, documentation

I am doing the HTML format documentation for my C# code and I'd like to know if it's possible to do a reference inside my own code.

For example:

```
public class Test{
public bool Calculate(int x){ //code }
}

public class Check{
void Checking(int y, int x, int z){
//code
bool aux = Test.Calcultate(x);
//code
}
```

When I'm doing the documentation like this:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// 
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name=""></param>
 /// <returns></returns>
```

How I can do a reference into documentation from the method Checking to the method Calculate? I mean, if I'm watching the documentation of the method Checking, there must be a link to Calculate

Comment: You mean something like this? `This uses the <see cref="Test.Calculate"/> method` in the summary?

Comment: Yes, dude, that's exactly what I need! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`<see>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/see) element, for example:

```
/// <summary>
/// This uses the <see cref="Test.Calculate"/> method
/// </summary>
/// <param name=""></param>
/// <returns></returns>
void Checking(int y, int x, int z)
{
    //code
    bool aux = Test.Calcultate(x);
    //code
}
```

This will show up in IntelliSense like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<see>` tag. See its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/see). For example, put in the `<remarks>` section of the `Checking` function:

```
<see cref="Calculate"/>
```

and you will get a link to the documentation page of the `Calculate` function. Note that documentation tags work only in xml documentation comments. You can put them in comments in your code, but you will not get a link.